# QOpenGLShaderProgram: is possible to make error output nice?

Tags: qt, opengl, error-handling, shader, gpu

I'm implementing some numerical algorithms on GPU via OpenGL and Qt.
But i am not very familiar with it.
I want to extract some functions from my current shader to some "shader library" and use it in my other shaders by string interpolation. It not hard to implement but i don't know how handle shader's compile errors

I use following code to compile shader

```
QOpenGLShaderProgram *shaderProgram = new QOpenGLShaderProgram();
if (!shaderProgram->addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Fragment,fragmentShaderFileName)) {
    qDebug() << "Failed to compile fragment shader";
    //..........
```

When some compile error appears Qt print following message (an example)

```
QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): 0:331(9): error: syntax error, unexpected NEW_IDENTIFIER, expecting ',' or ';'

*** Problematic Fragment shader source code ***
//my shader source code
```

Is possible to catch error line number and use it to build my own error message? (with highlighted line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Qt documentation, you can use [`QOpenGLShaderProgram::log()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglshaderprogram.html#log):

> Returns the errors and warnings that occurred during the last link()
>   or addShader() with explicitly specified source code.

You can then parse the resulting string to build your own error message.